# How to change mode of operation dynamically in MITMPROXY

Tags: mitmproxy

How to change flow mode conditionally. In my case some requests have to go through an upstream proxy and some don't need to (regular mode). Last time I checked it with mitmproxy this feature was not there. Is there a way to change flow mode dynamically now?

Comment: You could try to write a python based plugin for mitmproxy. Internally Mitmproxy provides the function `change_upstream_proxy_server`.

Comment: @Robert `change_upstream_proxy_server` doesn't change the flow mode, all it does is to change the upstream server. I don't now if there is a way to change the flow mode during runtime.

Comment: So you have tried to disable forwarding data to the upstream proxy using `change_upstream_proxy_server`? If not please describe what you mean by "flow mode".

Comment: @Robert [flow modes](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/) are defined here and `change_upstream_proxy_server` only changes the upstream proxy server and in case the upstream proxy is down or something the flow mode doesn't fall back to regular mode automatically.

Comment: So you want to switch between regular and reverse mode at runtime? Sorry but that doesn't make any sense because the client needs to know if it should send a CONNECT request (regular mode) or just work without CONNECT call (transparent mode). BTW: How is the relation to the "upstream proxy"?

Comment: @Robert between `regular` mode and `upstream` modes at runtime. In regular mode there is no upstream proxy and the mitmproxy client doesn't need to co CONNECT and the request is forwarded to the target server without any other middle man. In the upstream mode the request is forwarded to another proxy (CONNECT) and then that proxy forwards the request to the server. The thing is when the flow mode is configured inruntime it is locked in place and doesn't change.